# launch google maps in IOS with multiple waypoints

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.forms, google-maps-urls

I need to launch google maps with multiple waypoint showing on map on IOS using url in my Xamarin forms application.
I'm able to launch it with 2 points (Source and Destination) using this url:

```
comgooglemaps-x-callback://?zoom=14&saddr= " + App.UserCurrentLatitude + "," + App.UserCurrentLongitude + "&daddr=" + item.xpos + "," + item.ypos + "&directionsmode=driving
```

how can I show multiple points on map?

I tried adding this but didn't help.

```
waypoints=24.743449,46.658885/24.744560,46.660666
```

anyone??

Comment: Does it need to be google maps on iOS? Using Xamarin.Forms.Maps it would use google maps on android and apple maps on iOS. It would give you a lot of functionality cross platform ootb

Comment: @James yes, because then i have to implement all the features myself like drawing route, navigation etc. So it would be easier for me to just launch the map with specified parameters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a lot of googling, I made it work like this:

```
comgooglemaps - x - callback://?zoom=14&saddr= " + App.UserCurrentLatitude + "," + App.UserCurrentLongitude + "&daddr=" + item.xpos + ",+" + item.ypos + "+to:24.123456,+24.234567&directionsmode=driving
```

In case if anyone else is looking for the same.